# Slight chirping noise from front wheel base after new brake pads

Tags: brakes, noise, brake-rotor

I had the dealership put on new front brake pads on my 2013 Corolla and do a brake line flush for maintenance.

I noticed when the car is accelerating there will be a slight chirping noise coming from the front wheel base. It usually happens when the cars gets warmed up after I have been driving for about 5 minutes.

Is this normal with the new brake pads? Even when I am not braking?

Comment: No, it's not normal. Take it back.

Comment: By any chance could this be where the brake pads need to seed?

Comment: Brake pad break in usually occurs during the first 30 stops. If they're squealing after that, take it back to the shop